# ¿Es posible enviar dos datos al mismo en tiempo con un solo radio button?

Tags: html, angular, typescript

lo que intento hacer es enviar dos datos a firebase con un solo radio button

```
    <h1>¿QUIERES...?</h1>
<input type="radio"  value='arrendamiento' value='rentar'  formControlName="opcion"  name="opcion"/>
<label >rentar</label><br>
```

Comment: Hola. Cual es tu intención al querer enviarlos así?

Answer (score 0):

tal como lo tienes no se puede, tienes que añadir estos datos que quieres enviar a metodo (change)="enviardosdatos($event)". Por ejemplo:

```
 <mat-radio-button value="1" (change)="change($event)">Option 1</mat-radio-button>
```

y metodo que tienes que adaptar a tu solucion por que no has proporcionado como quieres guardar estos datos en firebase

```
change(event: MatRadioChange) {
    if (algo == event.value) {
      const dato1 = 'algo';
      const dato2 = 'otro';
      const data = {dato1, dato2}
      this.db.collection('tablacondosdatos').add(data);
    }
  }
```